# VueJS / JavaScript - own touch gestures - disable Edge touch gestures

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microsoft-edge

for a new hmi project in my company, I am using a plugin for touch gestures for a VueJS project.

The problem is: some of mine gestures are overlapping with the browser default touch gestures of the microsoft edge browser, which are used in kiosk mode.

Is it possible to deactivate the edge touch gestures and only use my defined touch gestures?

Thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: You must give more info about your problem. Try to define what's the plugin and how you use it.

Comment: You can try [`touch-action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) CSS property. `touch-action` is used to specify whether or not the browser should apply its default touch behavior to a region. You can try using `touch-action: none` to disables the browser's default touch behavior, then register your own touch event.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried this way?

```
@touchstart.native.stop
@touchmove.native.stop
@touchend.native.stop
```

.... and all touch if you want to stop 
hope i could help